# Adding a validation rule based on the response of API call to third party system

Tags: rest-api, api, validation, validation-rule

We are integrating our salesforce instance into a third-party system.

I have to stop the users from editing a field in Salesforce when certain values are not matching. To accomplish this, the third party wants me to add a validation rule in Salesforce which works based on the response that I receive by making the API call to their system.

Is this a good design to create a validation rule in Salesforce in the first place? As I have to show them a message and stop them from editing a field, waiting for an API response by making an asynchronous call to their system would take time, isn't it? And this creates a delay in saving the record for the user and affects user experience, isn't it?

If yes, is there any other alternative solution or design for this? Can someone add their response to this question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The options are covered in [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/data-integration) decision guide, please take a look.

Comment: I don't think this is really a technical question but more a question about business logic. Is it correct in terms of business logic that your record should be 'locked' as long as it is waiting for the asynchronous update? If so, then a validation rule is a good solution.